# Unnecessary discrimator column in TPC - EF 6, code first

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am trying to generate schema from class hierarchy:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class BaseTransaction : BaseEntity
{
// common fields
}

public class MyTransaction : BaseTransaction
{
// type-specific fields
}
```

DbContext config in fluent API:

```
public DbSet<MyTransaction> MyTransactions { get; set; }

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyTransaction>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("MyTransactions");
    });
 // ...
 }
```

I would like to get one table containing all fields (iherited from all superclasses).
This aspect works but EF generates the Discriminator column: Discriminator (nvarchar(128), null) that is typical for TPH.
I want to use TPC explicitly.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

If anyone, by any chance, happens to have similar issue please check if you got some classes inheriting from the classes that are mapped with an additional Discriminator column.

EF adds this column if certain class is part of the inheritance chain.